# how to load JS from a chrome extension popup

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

## background

I simply want to create a chrome extension where I click on the extension icon, it loads a popup that loads a javascript file.

I was able to do an html only popup simply by adding these two files:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  ..    
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    ..
  }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<html>
    ..
    hello world
</html>
```

## problem

I want to actually load a chrome [events page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) so that the popup page calls the events page and interacts with it.

## what i have tried

I added this to **manifest.json**

```
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["eventsPage.js"],
    "persistent": false
  }
```

and added a simple **eventsPage.js** file:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(onInit);
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(onStartup);

function onInit() {
  console.log("on init");
}

function onStartup() {
  console.log("on startup");
}

if (chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.onStartup) {
  chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function() {
    console.log('on startup stuff');
  });
}
```

when I launch the extension and click on inspect to see chrome dev tools.. nothing shows up on the console:

[image]

I've also tried adding the src of **eventsPage.js** to **popup.html**:

```
</head> 
  ..
  <script src="eventsPage.js"></script>
  <body>
  ..
```

but that changes nothing, I can't even find the eventsPage.js source in chrome dev tools.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ways:

1. Add a script for example `popup.js` in `popup.html` and call [`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function callback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getBackgroundPage) to interact with event page.

   popup.html

   ```
   ...
   <script src="popup.js"></script>
   ...
   ```

   popup.js

   ```
   chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(backgroundPage => backgroundPage.testMethod());
   ```

   eventsPage.js

   ```
   const testMethod = () => console.log('test');
   ```
2. Use [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)(there are many examples in this link) to communicate with event page.
3. Since you want to transfer data between popup page and event page, there are many other workarounds, for example, we could use global storage such as [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) to save/load/react to changes.

Comment: 1. you are using background page and events page interchangeably.. they're not the same.. background pages are deprecated
2. it would be nice if you can write some sample code

Comment: @abbood, in fact background page is not deprecated and it's just served for different purposes. I have added some simple sample and it should be an easy task for you ( you're experienced in iOS :) )

Comment: here is a follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41758616/getting-cannot-access-a-chrome-url-even-though-im-not-calling-it