# getting Cannot access a chrome:// URL even though i'm not calling it

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

## Background

I simply want to run the google drive sample call listed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js) in a chrome extension pop-up.The following is an excerpt of the actual original code that works on a regular html page:

**original html that works:**

```
  <script>
  function handleAuthClick(event) {
    gapi.auth.authorize(
    ..
  }
  </script>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      ..
      <button id="authorize-button" onclick="handleAuthClick(event)">
        Authorize
      </button>
```

---

## Explanation

I want to convert the above to a chrome extension that appears on a pop-up.. this is what i have (see complete code at [github repo](https://github.com/abbood/chrome-extension-test)):

**manifest.json**

```
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions": [
      "tabs","activeTab","https://apis.google.com/*"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com/*; 
                              object-src 'self'"
```

**popup.html**

```
  ..
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
      ..
      <button id="authorize-button">
        Authorize
      </button>
```

**popup.js**

```
window.onload = function () {
    var otherWindows = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=checkAuth"});
    var button = document.getElementById('authorize-button');
    button.onclick = function(event) {
        otherWindows.handleAuthClick(event);
    }
 }
```

**background.js**

```
function handleAuthClick(event) {
  // gapi is defined in https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?
  gapi.auth.authorize(
   ...
}
```

---

## problem

I get this error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: 
  Cannot access a chrome:// URL
    at chrome-extension://cmfbnommmmeccnkbochkfakncgnebckn/popup.js:3:17
    at chrome-extension://cmfbnommmmeccnkbochkfakncgnebckn/popup.js:5:3
```

Comment: And the auth is working, correct?

Comment: no it's not.. gapi is not defined so i can't make it work

Comment: Out of curiosity, your ``handleAuthClick`` is executed on page load (not after finishing load), not on cllick of the button the user can press. Perhaps it is trying to authorise before everything (included gapi script) has loaded in?

Comment: Currently you inject client.js in the webpage, not in the popup. See extensions overview: architecture.

Comment: @wOxxOm you mean this right? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch

Comment: Yes. It seems you're clicking the popup while a chrome:// page is in the active tab (for example, the new tab page is chrome://newtab). Also, see executeScript docs: it should be a file from the extension package or literal code, not a remote url.

Comment: @wOxxOm execute scripts? you mean this link? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript? are you writing this while driving? 

Comment: Yes and yes, I'm driving.

Comment: ok buddy take a look when you're done driving.. basically i'm not sure how i can be on a different chrome tab when my app just shows a very simple popup.. you can see the visual in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41756849/how-to-load-js-from-a-chrome-extension-popup.. and i uploaded my code to a github repo just for fun: https://github.com/abbood/chrome-extension-test

Comment: oh that's right.. i'm doing all my testing while being on the chrome://extensions page! ok i'll test on a "regular" page

Comment: @wOxxOm I've moved the remote file to a local client.js.. and chnaged the line to `chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:"client.js"});`.. but still no luck (ie it tells me gapi is not defined).. do i have to edit manifest.json as well?

Comment: @wOxxOm here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020384/cannot-find-chrome-extension-manifest-file